# How to Vectorise data

Tags: vector-space-models, vector-database

I have a set of data points that have various attributes (product, geography, unit, date). I then have incoming data with the same attributes.

I want to vectorise my data set to find the closeness of incoming data.

I can turn my product and geography tree into (distinct) graphs, then use node2vec to turn these two graphs into vectors.

I don’t then understand how to combine these vectors and also add date into the vector as an equal weight?

What is this practice of turning custom data into vectors called? (I’ve tried googling but am met with lots of shallow articles about running embedding models over text or images)

## Example

E.g our data set might be

Product: A::B::C (where C is a child of B is a child of A)
Geography: Spain
Date: 2014-01-01

Product: A::D::C
Geography: Portugal
Date: 2015-05-06

And a new piece of data comes in

Product: A::B
Geography: Europe
Date: 2015-05-06

Here the incoming data is closest to the first entry on product (a parent), equally close to both on geography, and an exact match to the second on date. I’d like to combine all these to find the closest entry (in reality there are thousands to match against)

Comment: Can you include a concrete example row of data or a simplified mock-up of what you're ultimately trying to do? It made sense for the most part but I didn't understand what you meant about having dates with equal weight.

Comment: @AustinCapobianco I’ve added an example. I’d like to combine the vector from my product graph, the vector from my geography graph and the vector of dates into a single vector such that all three of these factors have equal weighting. (And answer the more general question of how I can learn to convert data into vectors)